# Removing a row from a React state array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, state

I'm creating a dynamic report that you can add/ delete products from both list

1. 1st list being the products order
2. 2nd being the rest of the products in the db

I only want to call my api when hitting the submit button so until that point everything should be updated in my state.

The Add button works perfectly fine with the code bellow:

```
function onAddClicked(productId){
        let newProduct = filteredProducts.find(x => x.productId === productId);
        let updatedProductList = purchaseOrderDetails;
        newProduct.adjustByAmount = newProduct.total;
        updatedProductList.push(newProduct);
        setPurchaseOrderDetails(updatedProductList);
        filterDuplicates(filteredProducts, purchaseOrderDetails);
}
```

where setPurchaseOrderDetails is the products on order and filterDuplicates sets the state for the rest of the products all working fine here.

However, on my Delete function the state of the rest of the products seem to update but the ones on the order don't seem to go down in number as the state stays the same.

```
function onDeleteClicked(productId){
        let excludedProducts = filteredProducts;
        let deletedIndex = purchaseOrderDetails.findIndex(x => x.productId === productId);
        let productToDelete = purchaseOrderDetails[deletedIndex];
        productToDelete.total = 0;
        productToDelete.adjustByAmount = 0;
        let detailsToUpdate = purchaseOrderDetails.filter(x => x.id !== productToDelete.id)
        
        console.log('updateDetails', detailsToUpdate)
        excludedProducts.push(productToDelete);
        console.log('updateFilter', excludedProducts)
        setPurchaseOrderDetails(detailsToUpdate);
        setFilteredProducts([...filteredProducts]);
        console.log('stateDetail', purchaseOrderDetails)
        console.log('stateFilter', filteredProducts)
}
```

I've also console logged before my setPurchaseOrderDetails and i can see the filter is working fine but when it gets to the point where in needs to update the state it does not.

Answer (score 0):

the filteredProducts is not changing when you use here:
->setFilteredProducts([...filteredProducts]);

you push the productToDelete to excludedProducts not in the filteredProducts

Answer (score 0):

First all setState is always async, so setPurchaseOrderDetails and setFilteredProducts are async too. Thus whatever the updates you made to state will not reflect immediately in the next line.

You can print them in some async call backs like setTimeout after you update the state or anywhere in the component re-render flow.

You might have confused by looking at filteredProducts value as its value reflected immediately after state update. It's not happening because of state update it's indeed happening because of both filteredProducts and excludedProducts are pointing to same reference and you've new element to excludedProducts.

So to avoid these kind of confusions I would suggest you to clone state before modifying it.

You can better write your delete function like below

```
function onDeleteClicked(productId) {
  const productToDelete = purchaseOrderDetails.find(x => x.id === productId);
  const detailsToUpdate = purchaseOrderDetails.filter(x => x.id !== productId);

  setPurchaseOrderDetails(detailsToUpdate);
  setFilteredProducts([
    ...filteredProducts,
    { ...productToDelete,
      total: 0,
      adjustByAmount: 0
    }
  ]);

}
```